# Declaration of global range variable causes automation error

Tags: excel, vba

This question is about a peculiar occurence of Excel's somewhat mysterious error message "Automation Error -- Catastrophic Failure". It occurs when I open a specific Excel file that has VBA code where some range variables are declared at the modular level, outside of any sub or function. Details follow.

*UPDATE: After further troubleshooting I think I have isolated the problem. I might post a new question since a complete update would probably be too confusing. END UPDATE*

*UPDATE 2: Now I've have posted [a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46058096/5457466) with some additional clarification.*

I have an Excel file with VBA code used to track inventory. On one sheet I have a table with merchendise items with several fields such as item number, item name, etc. I have written several user-defined functions that return various item properties as a function of the item number. These UDFs are based on a combination of the regular worksheet functions `INDEX` and `MATCH`.

In particular, I have a function called `ITEM_NAME()` as illustrated in the screenshot (table minimized for simplicity):

[image: Function ITEM_NAME illustrated]

The code for `ITEM_NAME()` follows; note that the two *Range* variables are declared outside the scope of the function (the function `ITEM_NUMBER_EXISTS` called by `ITEM_NAME` basically checks the validity of the provided argument, but the code is not shown here):

```
Option Explicit

Dim mrngItemNumber As Range
Dim mrngItemName As Range

Public Function ITEM_NAME(varItemNumber As Variant) As String
' Returns Item Name as a function of Item Number.
    ' Return value error if argument is invalid:
    If Not ITEM_NUMBER_EXISTS(varItemNumber) Then
        ITEM_NAME = CVErr(xlErrNA)
        Exit Function
    End If
    ' The rest is executed only if the argument is a valid item number.
    Set mrngItemNumber = Range("A4:A6")
    Set mrngItemName = Range("B4:B6")
    ITEM_NAME = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(mrngItemName, _
    Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(varItemNumber, mrngItemNumber))
End Function
```

Since I have quite a lot of functions (not shown here) in the same module, I prefer to declare all the range variables as modular variables in the beginning of the code, as in the example above, and then assign them with the `Set` keyword inside the respective functions (and avoid having to declare them separately in each function).

Now, with the code written as in this example, I get the annoying error message when the file is opened. But the error disappears if I do any of the following:

1) change the variable type of `mrngItemNumber` and `mrngItemName` from `Range` to something else, such as `Integer` (although this obviously destroys the functions); or

2) move the declarations into the scope of the function `ITEM_NAME`.

After the error message appears, I can't really detect any actual problems with the file, it seems to be working normally.

To add to the confusion, I fail to replicate the issue with my minimal example above. But the problem has now occured with two different files: The first time I just suspected it was a compatibility issue since the original file was created on Office for Mac 2008, but the second time I'm working with a file that was built from scratch in Excel 2016 on Windows.

I've seen similar problems reported elsewhere (at [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31888880) and [Microsoft Technet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/341479ae-903a-423e-9a51-c3456ae7ad13/automation-error-catastrophic-failure?forum=excel)), but none with this particular flavor. Solutions suggested include checking that external references are working, and that no Excel process is running in the background. I have checked for both these issues but they don't seem to be connected to what I am experiencing. I've also checked that I have the latest update of Excel. (The file has one external reference (to `personal.xlsb`), and it is working as normal.)

I can't figure out why I get this error?

Comment: You mention that you have multiple sheets, but you don't declare the ranges sheet specifically. That would be a good start, else they might point to undesired worksheets, making your function fail. Other thing is to declare your ranges public, not as dim. So: Public mrngItemnumber As Range

Comment: Good point about sheets, but unfortunately to no effect (also, in my original file I'm using named ranges to avoid ambiguity). Note that it's actually not the function that fails, I get the error simply when the file is loading, before the function has been called by any process. After the error message the function indeed works as intended. I already played around with dim/public/private/global, but it does not affect this particular issue.